# echo output to a file shows repeated lines

Tags: bash

I created a Bash Script that is running some commands and It does echo to output information to a file. However, the output file shows double lines for each echo in script. For instance:

#### Bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
#VARIAVEIS
(...)
LOG=${ANO}-${MES}-${DIA}.HISTORICO.BACKUP.LOG.MYSQL.TXT
(...)
DIRTEMP=/root/temp
(...)
echo "======================================================"  >>$DIRTEMP/$LOG
echo "HISTÓRICO BACKUP DO LOG DO MYSQL NO SERVIDOR WEB/SENAC"  >>$DIRTEMP/$LOG
echo "======================================================"  >>$DIRTEMP/$LOG
(...)
```

#### Output file

`/root/temp/${ANO}-${MES}-${DIA}.HISTORICO.BACKUP.LOG.MYSQL.TXT`

```
(...)
======================================================
======================================================
HISTÓRICO BACKUP DO LOG DO MYSQL NO SERVIDOR WEB/SENAC
HISTÓRICO BACKUP DO LOG DO MYSQL NO SERVIDOR WEB/SENAC
======================================================
======================================================
(...)
```

The script is called from crontab:

```
55      23      *       *       *       /etc/run.backup.log.mysql & 1> dev/null
```

I don't know what's wrong. Can someone help?

Comment: What you show as a script should not produce the result you see.  Is all the output to the log file doubled, or is it just the output from `echo` that's doubled?  Is there any chance you've somehow got an alias for `echo` that prints twice?  Have you considered a one-time redirection of standard output to the log file:  `exec >>$DIRTEMP/$LOG` as a line on its own.  All further standard output from the script or the commands it executes will go to the log file unless you override it with explicit redirection.

Comment: If the double lines are in lock-step as shown, whatever is happening is more likely in your script than in the calling environment.  If the double lines get out of step, then the problem might be concurrent running of two copies of the script.  What happens when you run the script manually?  What happens if you run `bash -x /etc/run.backup.log.mysql`?  Note that the I/O redirection in the `crontab` line occurs after the process is run in background and doesn't affect the backup command itself.  The `&` marks the end of a command (as does `|`, `;`, etc -- in the absence of escapes, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Your script is OK! 
You should review the way this script is being called.

Comment: If you run it directly, without the use of cron, the result is the same?

Comment: In fact, I had created a test script and scheduled the crontab to run it few minutes later The output file resulted hasn't duplicated lines. It's so very strange!

Comment: @SidneiRudolf you can ask questions like that in our stackover flow  portuguese "já que metade do seu script está em português" :)

Comment: :)
Thanks, gpupo.

But I prefer writting in english becouse almost users here write and read in english. I don't have difficult to write or read texts in english.